# How do you add not equal to function to the default values of a report parameter?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, default

I have a list of value and I want to default to all but 1 of them.  but I don't want to have to add 10 unique value functions, is a <> "Value" possible?

Comment: please explain your question in details

Answer (score 2):

Is your multi-value parameter based on a query? If so, just select the default values for the parameter from a query that excludes the value you want to ignore.

For example, if the parameter values are gotten from the query:

```
SELECT Code, Description
FROM CodeTable
```

then use the following query for your default values:

```
SELECT Code, Description
FROM CodeTable
WHERE Code <> "NotThisCOde"
```

Comment: I am using a data set query to populate the multi value parameter, however, if I exclude it in the query, the end user looses the ability to select "Not this Code" in adhoc.

Comment: The way I have it set up right now, for my parameter properties under Default values, I have to Specify values for each unique value, I find it hard to believe that SSRS doesn't allow a <> value in the specify values function.

Comment: I am suggesting two queries - one to display all values and one for default values that excludes the code you don't want